# Carthage does not build main framework

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

Lets say 2 Frameworks A & B are created. Inside framework A, using Cartthage framework B is included. Now when I include framework A in a project using carthage, it checks out both of them but only builds B.

What should I do to get framework A also built ?

Cartfile for framework A:

```
git "http://location/to/fwk/b" "branch"
```

Cartfile for Project:

```
git "http://location/to/fwk/a" "branch"
```

Once I run `carthage update` from the project location, I can see from the logs that both frameworks are checked out but in the build location I can only see Framework B.

Also tried adding framework B to Cartfile.private but it didnt help

Comment: What are your cartfiles, what commands are you using? This is almost certainly user error and you haven't provided enough information to see where it is.

Comment: @WillM. added cartfile contents

Comment: Perhaps Framework A is failing to build due to an error in the code. There should be logs from the build process that say what frameworks are being built and the result of the process.

Comment: @WillM. Thought the same, so I started to test the scenario with empty framework (just a class and a silly method to log), but its the same issue

Comment: and the logs dont say anything?

Comment: From the carthage docs the only thing it lists for nested dependencies is:  *If the framework you want to add to your project has dependencies explicitly listed in a Cartfile, Carthage will automatically retrieve them for you. You will then have to drag them yourself into your project from the Carthage/Build folder.*I guess is this not even possible because the dependency isn't being built? What does the log say when you run `carthage update --no-skip-current`

Comment: @WillM. I don't see any errors, just that `=== BUILD TARGET FrameworkA OF PROJECT FrameworkA WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===` and then `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **`

Comment: @LouisTur Its the same log, no errors reported, it just builds Framework B and stops at that.

Comment: Is it possible to list which framework you're trying to use so that I can try it on a clean project?

Comment: @LouisTur its a private git server, but let me try the same scenario with GitHub frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Open project framework A and select shared scheme from Manage scheme. Then run the command carthage update.